# Building FFMPEG with VS2017, unresolved WinAPI externals

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, linker

I have successfully built ffmpeg with VS2017 using make command.
But I need to debug ffmpeg so I created a VS project. I have added ffmpeg files and
stuck in linking stage.
I have a lot of unresolved external symbol errors on WinAPI functions. All of them are defined in kernel32.lib. I have kernel32.lib linked. The error looks like this:

unresolved external symbol __imp__LoadLibraryExA referenced in function _win32_dlopen

Are there any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks

UPD: I have partially solved this issue. I started comparing command line options for cl.exe and link.exe. Then I compared *.obj files using dumpbin /symbols to check WinAPI imports. I found that WinAPI mangling differs. Then I compared cl.exe command line options and found that /D _MSC_VER is responsible for that. I removed that definition and linking errors disappeared. I will figure out later how this definition affects mangling.

Comment: How did you link kernel32.lib?

Comment: When I created console project in visual studio kernel32.lib was in "Additional Dependencies" line. In settings. Visual studio wizard added this file.

Comment: I have managed to solve that issue partially.